# Create a table matrix with 2d arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am trying to create a program where you ask the user for a number, Create an array that is as close to square as you can and fill it with 1 to the user's specified number. You have to use a 2d array. Here is an example of what it would look like:

user input: **16**

output:  `1  2  3  4
        5  6  7  8
        9  10 11 12
        13 14 15 16`

I have tried to do it by running it trough loops but it has not worked, I hope someone can guide me on how to do this

Comment: What's the question? You want someone writes such program istead of you?

Comment: I have tried to do it by running loops but it has not worked, so I am asking for help

Comment: Add the code loops that you tried to the question, so we can see what might have been wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's get the user input:

```
int num;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num) || num < 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!");
}
```

after this calculate the side of the square:

```
var sideLength = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(num));
```

then create the 2D array:

```
var array = new int[sideLength, sideLength];
```

and write the numbers into it:

```
for (int row = 0; row < sideLength; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < sideLength; column++)
    {
        var value = row * sideLength + (column + 1);
        if (value > num)
            break;
        array[row, column] = value;
    }
}
```

but don't write anything higher then the user input, this will leave them `0`, which is great because you want to display it from `1` so you can use the `0` to detect the end in case the user input is not a square number.

Now let's prepare a string to format the numbers. If you want all numbers to be the exact same length you can format it with `int.ToString("0")` where the number of `0`s will set the length. Let's create a string which will make all number the same length. The user input is the longest possible number so you can use that to create the string:

```
var format = new string('0', num.ToString().Length);
```

Now print the array:

```
for (int row = 0; row < sideLength; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < sideLength; column++)
    {
        var value = array[row, column];
        if (value == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            goto breakBoth;
        }
        Console.Write($"{value.ToString(format)} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
breakBoth:
```

This will put the same number of numbers in a line and there will the same amount of rows unless it finds a `0`, then it will stop and the last line won't be a full line, this happens if the input wasn't a square number.

Let's look at the outputs:

**Input:** 16

**Output:**

```
01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08
09 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

**Input:** 14

**Output:**

```
01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08
09 10 11 12
13 14
```

If you want to display the `0`s if it's not a full line you can remove the 0 check from the print part.

**Can this be optimized?**

Yes! The array is useless, it just contains incrementing numbers. If 2d arrays are not a requirement you can completely remove it and make some modifications to the print function.

```
int num;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!");
}


var sideLength = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(num));
var format = new string('0', num.ToString().Length);
for (int row = 0; row < sideLength; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < sideLength; column++)
    {
        var value = row * sideLength + (column + 1);
        if (value > num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            goto breakBoth;
        }
        Console.Write($"{value.ToString(format)} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
breakBoth:
```

This code does the same thing but without 2d arrays.

Comment: This definitely makes sense, what does the "Math.Ceiling" function do?

Comment: @vanquish_vi It rounds up the result of the square root function. Casting a `double` to an `int` rounds it down which means you wouldn't get the whole table unless it's a square number (when the result of the square root function is an integer). By rounding up you get the whole output but it's not always a square (for example with 14 as input). I recommend you remove it and try it yourself with different inputs.